# How to return multiple tables separately

Tags: lua, lua-table

```
local subMaps = {["Map Name"] = {["SubMap Name"] = {{105, 51, 167, 91}, {137, 92, 167, 103}, {122, 97, 127, 99}, {128, 99, 136, 102}}}} --each table is (minX, minY, maxX, maxY)

local rect = subMaps["Map Name"]["SubMap Name"]

    if rect then
        for i,v in ipairs(rect) do
            print(unpack(rect[i]))
        end
    end
```

The above code prints this:

105 51  167 91
137 92  167 103
122 97  127 99
128 99  136 102

How can I take each of those 4 tables and use them in my function `getNearestCell(minX, minY, maxX, maxY)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (rect) then
    for i,v in ipairs(rect) do
        local cell = getNearestCell(unpack(v));
        print(tostring(cell),type(cell));
    end
end
```

Your code is correct, just need to replace the print call with your function.

Also you do not need to access `rect` in your loop (`rect[i]`) `v` already holds your table.